# How does Bundler know what environment to use?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, ruby-on-rails-3

Here's probably a very "newbieish" question on Bundler, but I'm wondering how bundle install knows what environment to use or how to set it? Or do I even need to? My problem is that I've grouped my gems (in Gemfile) by environments and when deploying now I only want production gems to be installed.

Answer (score 30):

At the top of the `application.rb` file you can see

```
# If you have a Gemfile, require the gems listed there, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env) if defined?(Bundler)
```

When Rails is booted, Bundler automatically loads all the dependencies for the `:default` group and current environment.

Please note that when you run `bundle install`, Bundler resolves and install dependencies for all the environments, unless you specify a `--without option`

```
$ bundle install --without staging development test
```

In production, you might also want to add the `--deployment` flag.

[More info about bundle install](http://gembundler.com/bundle_install.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "group" option in the gem deependency declaration. Check this ASCIICast: http://asciicasts.com/episodes/201-bundler