# "bundle info puma" failed due to other uninstalled dependency

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I have a very basic rails application.

After running `bundle config set --local deployment true` and `bundle _2.4.10_ install`, I want to run `bundle info puma` to check if puma is installed successfully based on Gemfile. However, this command failed with error message `Could not find debug-1.8.0, web-console-4.2.1, capybara-3.39.2, selenium-webdriver-4.14.0, irb-1.8.3, reline-0.3.9, bindex-0.8.1, addressable-2.8.5, matrix-0.4.2, regexp_parser-2.8.2, xpath-3.2.0, rexml-3.2.6, rubyzip-2.3.2, websocket-1.2.10, rdoc-6.5.0, io-console-0.6.0, public_suffix-5.0.3, psych-5.1.1.1, stringio-3.0.8 in locally installed gems`.

I take a deeper look and find these dependencies in the error message are not installed because they are in `test` or `development` group of Gemfile and this may be expected. May I know why `bundle info puma` command cares about those dependencies instead of just checking `puma`? How can I run `bundle info puma` and let it ignore dependencies in those 2 groups?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does Bundler know what environment to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4426888/how-does-bundler-know-what-environment-to-use)

Comment: Hey @BerkhanBerkdemir, thanks for your response first. Actually it does not answer my question. I know how to install dependencies by group in Gemfile. My question is why `bundle info puma` cannot work when dependencies in other group are not installed.